# Why do i get the error message for a bool in a if statement

Tags: f#, boolean

I am trying to make an if statement, where it should see if the list is empty or not. Then it should return a bool of true or false. But i get the error message. How do i correct this.

> Lint: `if a then true else false` might be able to be refactored into `a`.

```
  let isGameOver (p : player ) (b : board) : bool =
  let fstb = fst b
  let sndb = snd b
    if List.sum (fst b) = 0 || List.sum (snd b) = 0 then
      true
    else 
      false
```

Comment: Ello, indentation is important in F#. Could you format such that indentation follows the syntax.
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` expression has the format `if a then true else false` so you can refactor it as suggested. You can also replace the use of `fst` and `snd` with pattern matching:

```
let isGameOver (p : player) (fstb, sndb) : bool =
  List.sum fstb = 0 || List.sum sndb = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do i get the error message for a bool in a if statement?
>   How do i correct this?

The part of the code you need to focus on is

```
if List.sum (fst b) = 0 || List.sum (snd b) = 0 then
      true
    else 
      false
```

The result of the if statement is `bool`, e.g. `true` or `false`

Lint is smart enough to know that you are using an `if` to return a `bool` and that the conditional part of the if statements is also a type `bool`. What lint is saying is that

```
if (expr) then
      true
    else 
      false
```

is not needed and can be done the same using just the expression.

So the change is to just use the expression part of the `if` like

```
List.sum (fst b) = 0 || List.sum (snd b) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an error message, but rather a message from the [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) that you might be able to refactor your code.

What the linter is hinting at, is that your function returns `true` whenever the expression `List.sum (fst b) = 0 || List.sum (snd b) = 0` is `true` and `false` whenever it is `false`. As such, the `if` statement is unnecessary.